# SQL Server XQuery: How to avoid "illegal qualified name character" exception?

Tags: xml, xquery

I'm working on a XQuery that may/can contain characters like ">", "<" and single quotes.

How do I avoid breaking the xml parser?

My xml form is like this

```
<root>
<container>
  <item>(d.Field <> 0)</item>
</container>
</root>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "XML" you've shown isn't XML.

Either of the following would be XML:

```
<root>
<container>
  <item>(d.Field &lt;&gt; 0)</item>
</container>
</root>
```

or:

```
<root>
<container>
  <item><![CDATA[(d.Field <> 0)]]></item>
</container>
</root>
```